# SonarQube - How to see more than the first 15 violations?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 5.3. We have 241k issues in our codebase. But when I filter out say, the "Major" issues and click on the "Rule" box to see what rules were violated, I can only see the first 15. Is there a way I can find out all of them?

I've edited this question to add a screenshot. Notice on the left under "Rule" there are only 15 of them.

[image]

Comment: The version is mentioned at the bottom of any webpage of your SonarQube server. :) Also, screenshot to illustrate your issue ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in the UI, but you can get the data you need using the Web API: `/api/issues/search` (documented [here](https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/issues/search)) can list all the issues of a given project (use `projectKeys`). And to your question: set the `facets` parameter to `rules` , the returned JSON will then list the violated rules (and even count the violations per rule).

Using [git project as an example](https://sonarqube.com/component_issues?id=git#resolved=false) here's an example of Web API request:

> https://sonarqube.com/api/issues/search?projectKeys=git&severities=CRITICAL&facets=rules&ps=250

**Edit**: via Web API, facet is still limited to top 15 elements. However one can programmatically loop through issues (results are paginated) and count rules along the way.

Comment: Thank you! But adding the facets parameter doesn't seem to have any affect... Severities does, but not Facets. Does it work for you?

Comment: Works for me indeed. Can you share the JSON that you get back from the Web API request ?

Comment: To be clear: this doesn't work in the UI. Only Web API can give you the exhaustive data. Answer edited.

Comment: What's the best way to show you that JSON? A screenshot? It's pretty unreadable though.

Comment: pastebin.com can help. JSON are better parsed then read indeed. You're looking for exhaustive data and there can be hundreds of rules to be listed, so while the UI can't do this, the Web API will let you get everything.

Comment: Ok, here's my pastebin URL: http://pastebin.com/sMZMMhTY. You'll see that each individual violation is listed. I expected the rules to be grouped together somehow.

Comment: It's there at the bottom, look for `"facets":[{"property":"rules","values":` . :)

Comment: Ah, I see!! But it still only shows the first 15... :-(

Comment: Please read the [API documentation](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/issues/search), results are paged. You should use `p` and `ps` to get the full list.

Comment: The "facets" property doesn't change when I increment the page. It still only shows the first 15. But I'll accept your answer! Thanks.